# Java - JSON Object and ListOrderedMap problem

Tags: java, websphere, nosuchmethoderror, apache-commons-collection

I am trying to use the JSON-lib api in my code to convert a java object into a JSONObject.

I have added all of the dependencies with the versions specified on the link below to my j2ee web module dependencies

http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

However, whenever I call the JSONObject.fromObject() method I get NoSuchMethodError.

I should also point out that **the exact same code and dependencies work on my tomcat server but do not work on my websphere application server**. Does anybody know what I may be doing wrong ?

Partial stack trace below:

```
 E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[SpringMVCServlet]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap.<init>()V
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:1450)
    at net.sf.json.util.CycleDetectionStrategy.<clinit>(CycleDetectionStrategy.java:37)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at net.sf.json.JsonConfig.<clinit>(JsonConfig.java:65)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:134)
```

Comment: Do you have the correct version of commons collection api? use a decompiler to figure out if you have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct version of commons collections jar in your `WEB-INF/lib` and then set the `"Classes loaded with application class loader first"` option in your WebSphere admin console as shown [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/trun_classload_entapp.html)

Comment: I solved the problem using by setting the application class loader to PARENT_LAST as specified here [http://www.coderanch.com/t/486721/JSF/java/JSF-websphere](http://www.coderanch.com/t/486721/JSF/java/JSF-websphere) This link is also useful for explaining websphere class loaders [http://www.technicalfacilitation.com/get.php?link=classloading](http://www.technicalfacilitation.com/get.php?link=classloading)